# Decreased MPG, clicking sound when pressing accelerator

Tags: honda, civic, exhaust, fuel-consumption

Over the past week, the MPG on my car has gone down significantly, about 3-4 MPG. My driving habits have not changed.

In the meantime, there is a distinct "pneumatic" clicking sound whenever I press the accelerator. It sounds like it's coming from the rear of the car, like the exhaust. It's more apparent the harder I press.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question?

Comment: Have you noticed any loss of power going up hill or accelerating?  The noise makes me think fuel pump is going bad.

Comment: 2016 Honda Civic, 15k miles. No noticeable loss in performance.

Comment: Petrol/diesel? It should still be covered under warranty, so why not make the manufacturer fix their stuff?

Comment: Have you actually measured an increase in fuel economy, or is that what the on-board computer is telling you? If it's the computer, is it possible you  changed the readout from lifetime to instantaneous or current tank mode? That kind of drop in MPG is very suspicious for what is essentially a brand new car.